# SimpleAmqpClient & rabbitmq-c binaries

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, rabbitmq-c

Are there pre-built per-platform binaries for the AMQP libraries SimpleAmqpClient & rabbitmq-c (and if no, what would be the reason)?

Answer (score 2):

you are really expected to build from source. Some open source sites will not allow binaries to be directly distributed, there is also the matter of choosing your own optimizations during compile time. Also, SimpleAmqpClient is C++ and the generated binaries are very toolchain specific.